# EntityForm Loop

Tags: entities

Is there a way to loop through entityform fields? Currently I'm pulling individual form values out like this, `$var = $entityform_wrapper->field_name->value();`

I'd like to do something like a foreach through the entityform, but everything I've tried has failed.

**Update:**

I have it working. The issue I'm running into now is for Value, it showing me "array", so I have to find the value in the value array.

I looked at field_get_items, entity_metadata_field_property_get and a few other functions but haven't figured out how to get the value.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
$entityform = entityform_load(40);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('entityform', $entityform);
$form = $wrapper->getPropertyInfo();

foreach ($form as $key => $value) {
echo "$key is $value \n";
}
```